# Setting values of bidimensional array by code

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I would like to set the values of a bidimensional array in the VBA code (because they are constants)

I know that I can set a monodimensional array with:

```
mArr = Array("1", "Hello", "World",  "I", "am", "Sam")
```

But I don't know how to do the same with a bidimensional array.

I also know that I can set the value of a single item of a multidimensional array with:

```
mArr (1, 3) = "World"
```

but I'm looking for a way to set all values at same time (or with minimum code).

Sorry if the question is foolish but I didn't find nothing about this on the web.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim v As Variant
v = Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4), Array(5, 6))
```

or in your case:

```
 mArr = Array(Array("1", "Hello"), Array("World", "I"), Array("am", "Sam"))
```

- from here:
  http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?40163-How-to-conveniently-fill-a-2-dimensional-array

Comment: This is an array of Arrays. I had thought of something like this but I never used it. Can you explaim me how to extract value of a single item? Thanks

Comment: This array will be 0 based.  Access like `v(1)(1)`  (= `4`)

Comment: @genespos if you are happy with a jagged array, then fine.  If you want a real 2D array, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shortcut Evaluate function to achieve this

Something like

```
mArr = [{"1", "Hello"; "World",  "I"; "am", "Sam"}]
```

This will result in a 1 based 3x2 variant array

Comment: Great stuff. The two options side by side as seen by Watch:


see pic here: http://postimg.org/image/p76ylyhlb/a04750c5/

Comment: Thanks, this is the real right answer to my question but this time I'll prefer using an array of arrays. I'll remember your answer for the future.

Comment: I tryed to use this with an array 1 to 5, 1 to 8 but it doesn't work: if I write all on the same line  I get "identifier too long" (translation from italian) if I use many lines with " _" it gives me error: "closing parenthesis missing" but highlights only the first line. What can I do?

Comment: Please write the code. It will help me give you an answer.

Comment: `MT = [{1, "Tipo", "Data Costituzione", "Data Rinuncia", "","", "",""; 2, "Tipo Atto", "Numero", "Parte","Data Deposito","","",""; 3, "Data Udienza", "Tipo Udienza", "Esito Discussione", "Relatore", "Raggruppamento", "Ordine Ruolo", ""; 5, "Tipo", "Numero", "Relatore", "Data Pubblicazione", "Data Udienza", "Tipo Udienza", "Esiti"; 5, "Tipo", "Numero", "Relatore", "Data Pubblicazione", "Esiti"}] ` - As I said, I'm using an Array of arrays and it works fine. This is only for understanding this command. Thanks